# Set expiration of password on keyring - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-keyring

I'm trying to figure out on how to set expiration of the password on the keyring.

Example: I want the password to be automatically deleted after 24hours or once the system is rebooted.

I just noticed that the password is restored in the system even after rebooting the machine. I have tried to look if this is possible but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Why do you think is a feature of this library?

Comment: @StephenRauch Sorry I didn't get your question.

Comment: You assume the python-keyring library can do this.  My quick look at the documentation does seem to indicate that this is something it supports.

Comment: Without much knowledge of keyring backends, I was also intent on doing this. However, I now think it is not as desirable a feature as I first thought. Simply deleting the password after some interval raises a lot of questions when you go to find look up the password and can't find it: did it expire or did something else mess with the keyring? _Can you expire a token?_ Playing around with the package and reading the code, I'm not seeing any references to expiry, auto-delete, etc. I think not.